# JPA: @ManyToOne didn't update reference automatically

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, playframework

I have two Entities `OrgType` and `OrgField`:

```
@Entity(name = "T_ORG_FIELD")
public class OrgField extends Model {
    @MinSize(value = 2)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String name;

    @ManyToOne
    public OrgType orgType;
    ...
}

@Entity(name = "T_ORG_TYPE")
public class OrgType extends Model {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orgType")
    public List<OrgField> orgFields = new ArrayList<OrgField>();
    ...
}
```

Now, I'm writing unit test for them:

```
public class OrganizationTest extends UnitTest {

    @Test
    public void saveOrRemoveOrg() {
        OrgType orgType = new OrgType("org type", "description");
        orgType.save();

        OrgField field = new OrgField();
        field.name = "field1";
        field.orgType = orgType;
        field.save();

        Model.em().flush();

        System.out.println(OrgField.count("name = ?", "field1")); // Output : 1

        int size = orgType.orgFields.size();
        assertEquals(1, size);   // Error , expect 1 but get 0.
        ...
```

I created a new OrgField and update its reference of orgType, and expected to have `orgType.orgFields` automatically be filled, but it didn't.

Any help ?

Comment: you can try em.find(orgType.id).orgFields.size(), or specify what your method '.save' do.

Comment: No, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fill **fetch** attribute as below:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)

@OneToMany(mappedBy="orgType", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

*FecthType.EAGER* will fetch it as you desire. You can define different values for each class, if you like. Instead, you can you *FetchType.LAZY*, it is a good practive to explicity set this attribute instead of leaving the default value to be used.

Moreover, you can use the attribute **cascade** with *CascadeType.ALL* to persist, etc. automatically as well, or check CascadeType enum to see other values. It is also a good practice to explicity define the value of **cascade** attribute.